# .htaccess Rewrite all

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rules in .htaccess. Unfortunately, it does not work due to the last rule (everything else works fine). Why?

```
Options -Indexes    
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^(cdn) - [L]    
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ backend_0.0.1/index.php/$1 [QSA,L]    
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ frontend_0.0.1/css.php/$1 [NC,QSA,E=no-gzip:1,L]    
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ frontend_0.0.1/js.php/$1 [NC,QSA,E=no-gzip:1,L]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend_0.0.1/index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

If I replace the last line by:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend_0.0.1/index.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Then it suddenly starts to work but previous rules are skipped and only this last rule is applied. But I need rules to stop rewriting once the first one mathches.

Comment: The [L] will prevent any further matches. So if the other rules are "skipped", it's because they don't match.

Comment: But they do match in the first example

Comment: Then enable the `RewriteLog` and see what's going on: RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exclude the destinations you are redirecting to:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(backend_0\.0\.1|frontend_0\.0\.1)/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend_0.0.1/index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```